# Help_how to make the user put on the funtion to derivate

Tags: scilab

I need that the user can enter the function to derivate

I have tried without the ´s´ but the result is an endless loop

z=input("Ingrese la funcion dx a resolver  ","s");//the user put the funtion

k=input("Ingrese el valor de la x  "); //The value of x

der= derivative(z,'x',k);//derivate

disp(der);

the error of this is Undefined variable: derivative

Answer (score 0):

First note that z you get with

```
  z=input("Ingrese la funcion dx a resolver ","s");
```

is not a function, just a character string.
I suppose you intend to enter expression in the varaible "x"  like:

```
 "x^2+3*x+1"
```

or
     "sin(3*x^3)+exp(4*x)"

once you have got the z expression you should build a Scilab function with

```
 deff("y=foo(x)","y="+z)
```

Which defines the Scilab function foo from x to y.
Note that Scilab is not able to compute formal derivatives
But you can compute approximate derivative value at a given point using the numderivative function

```
der=numerivative(foo,k)
```

Another way,: use of the Diffcode atoms module (to be installed). These gives "exact" results but may fail for some complicated functions and it requires more computation:

```
 xdx=diffcode_der(k,1)
 ydy=foo(xdx)
```